# How to view the entire output of a CMD window

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

I often use binaries that output their actions in a CMD window which is can be helpful to see what is going as commands are executed, but often the output of these commands are scrolled down by the CMD window to the point where I can no longer scroll back up to see the beginning of the execution of commands.

Is there a flag to enter with the CMD window that will print the entire output of a series of commands (allow me to scroll back up and see everything)?

Running Windows 10 Pro

Comment: maximum lines available in terminal/cmd is 9999 for scroll back. If you want to view the full log, you'll have to pipe the output to a log. This is done in different ways depending on what type of files you are installing. What types of files are you seeing the issue with? .msi /.exe etc ?

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I have come anywhere near 9999 lines. THe output is cutting off maybe at like 200 or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How far you can scroll depends on the terminal app and its settings.

### cmd.exe

Default `cmd.exe` has this option:

<kbd>Right mouse button on title bar</kbd> -> `Properties` -> `Layout` -> `Screen buffer size`

It can be increased only up to `9999` there. That limitation can be circumvented with not too consistent registry changes or with `mode con lines=32766` which is not permament and applies only to current window. It's also static and the scrollbar gets set to that instantly after window launch.

However, 3rd party apps have better implementations that can go up to the hard limit problemlessly and the scrollbar can also be dynamic.

### ConEmu & cmder

[ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) allows the maximum of `32766` and it's just a matter of changing [settings](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsSizePos.html#id2894) in the GUI:

<kbd>Right mouse button on title bar</kbd> -> `Settings...` -> `Size & Pos` -> Tick `Long console output` and enter `32766` in the textbox

### Windows Terminal

I don't use this too much so I'm not certain - you can enter bigger numbers than the maximum even, however, it seems like it [isn't supported yet](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1410) regardless and if you enter something bigger it gets reduced to the regular Windows limit. You can change it in:

<kbd>Right mouse button on title bar</kbd> -> `Settings` -> `Command Prompt` -> `Advanced` -> `History size`

Comment: Thanks for following up. I inputted 9999 in the height section of the window and it seems to work !